# can anyone tell me how to do seo friendly url in laravel 3

Tags: laravel, seo, laravel-3

i am using laravel 3 for my web application, i know how to route and all that stuff,it is seo friendly but i want to fetch data from textbox and include that in URL.

```
i want to include "java-complete-referance "` from textbox to URL.
```

like in search bar user enters for java complete rerence and i want to pass that data to route and url should be like  **myweb.com/catagory/books/java-complete-referance**.

laravel form having get and post option but how to pass that form data to route's get or post method and display that textbox value in url

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

your Route:

```
Route::get('category/(:any)/(:any)', array( 'uses' => 'Articles@show'));
```

now in your route get the category id by the name, and get the article id by the title(ofcourse you need to make sure that the title is uniqe when creating)

if you want to make search is the same.. get the category id by the name and get the search string from title (make some function to replace '-' by space)

```
public function Show($category_id,$article_title){

}
```

Comment: thanx @amir i am getting value of text box in Route::post('search',function(){
 $url_ptr = str_replace(" ", "-", Input::get('search'));
 return Redirect::to_route('result',$url_ptr);});
and result route is Route::get('book-results/(:any?)', array('as'=>'result', 'uses'=>'items@result')); its  working now

Comment: but i got other error in typeahead.js jquery due to that url,its not working now,when i type java in text box and my url changes to myweb.com/book-result/java and typeahead.js stopped working now but if i remove 'java' from url so it is  myweb.com/book-resul now  and click on tyoeahead.js textbox then its working fine autosuggestion is working but i want 'java' in url is there any relation of typeahead.js with url ? plz help i am really stuckd in this .

Comment: what the error you get? i guess that when you are in the url exmpla.ocm/book-reult/java and you try to search again it call that url: example.com/book-result/java/new-search and this route not exists

Comment: sorry i cant understand you... try to edit your original post and add the errors and the source code